# Use a JavaScript variable as part of a href link in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, variables

Part of my code:

```
<p id="demo">{$value.file_name}</p>

<script type="text/javascript">

var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
var res = str.replace("/var/www/html/biology/demo", "");
document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = res;

</script>

<a href="#para" id='para'>Download</a>
```

This part of the url will already be present: "a.b.c.d.edu/bio/cluster/"

$value.file_name contains "/var/www/html/biology/demo/files/mpijobs/107/mothership/data/job107_0_0_output.tif"

After the script, "para" contains the edited path which is "/files/mpijobs/107/mothership/data/job107_0_0_output.tif" (the removal of "**/var/www/html/biology/demo**")

The code:

```
<a href="{$value.file_name}">Download</a>
```

provides a clickable link to "a.b.c.d.edu/bio/cluster/**/var/www/html/biology/demo**/files/mpijobs/107/mothership/data/job107_0_0_output.tif"

and what I want to do is replace "{$value.file_name}" inside the  brackets with "para" (and what it represents) so that the download link is linked to

"a.b.c.d.edu/bio/cluster//files/mpijobs/107/mothership/data/job107_0_0_output.tif"

Comment: `<p id="demo">{$value.file_name}</p>` - Are you using Smarty by any chance?

Comment: "Smarty"? No, not using whatever that is. Why do you ask?

Comment: This => http://www.smarty.net/crash_course - that's why I asked. The syntax you're using is identical to what they use.

Comment: Are you trying to use a value to a link inside a div?

Comment: Are you asking to replace the <p> value with the <a href> tag?

Comment: No, I want to replace "{$value.file_name}" in the line "<a href="{$value.file_name}">Download</a>" with "para". "para" contains the shortened path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I misunderstood.

If the a href attribute is set like so:

```
<a href="{$value.file_name}">Download</a>
```

You can use in the javascript:

```
str.setAttribute("href", res);
```

EDIT:

Ok I got it. Sorry about this strenuous exercise. Here's what you should write:

```
<p id="demo">{$value.file_name}</p>
<a href="#para" id='para'>Download</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
var res = str.replace("/var/www/html/biology/demo", "");
para = document.getElementById('para');
para.href = res;

</script>
```

Comment: I tried this and didn't have success. All I'm looking to do is assign "demo" the value of "$value.file_name", enter the script and essentially remove part of that link, assign the shortened link to "para", exit the script and link to "para", the shortened link.

Comment: Possibly disregard my previous comment, you edited your answer while I typed. I'll look into this and get back to you.

Comment: I believe I'm not communicating what I'm looking to do in an adequate manner. So, $value.file contains the full path. I don't want to link to the full path, I want to link to a shortened version of that path. A portion of that full path needs to be removed as linking to it in its current, full, state returns a "page not routed" error. Once this path has been shortened within <script>...</script>, I want to somehow exit <script> while still having access to the shortened path. Basically, do as "<a href="{$value.file_name}">Download</a>" does, but with the shortened path.

Comment: Yeah I see. I'm going to keep editing this quickly so stay with me. Try this next edit.

Comment: This works, thanks. Now I have to figure out how to work this into a loop. There are n number of $value(s) ($value.file_name) and at the moment, the entirety of your code above is located in the "else" of the loop. I have to find a way for this code to work for the n number of $value(s) and return the correct shortened path for each one. The end of the path differs for each $value.file_name as these are paths to image segments. (Upload an image, image sent to the cluster, image broken into segments and returned). At the moment, the code is only working for the first segment path.

Comment: I can't guranatee this is the best way, but you could use store all the "value.file_names" in an array and then iterate over the entirety of the array in which you call this replace function on the each element. If it doesn't work, then go to this manual version. I can write this in the code above if you want.

Comment: Would relocating the script to the top of the html page and out of the loop possibly get this working? I imagine making what's in the script a function and calling the function from inside the "else" of the loop, may be a start to getting it working or possibly what needs to be done. If you have an idea, please share.

Comment: Yes, I would do that. Make a function that can sweep thru all the files and create a shortened version of that URL. I'm not sure where you're storing your URLs, but I would use an array of some sort to contain the long-URLS and then reduce the long one with the function to create a short-url version. This is, only of course, if you want to do it for all URLs in one go.